# Swagger Summary for Enum not showing

Tags: enums, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I am using xml annotations on my API endpoints which contain information about the endpoint responses as well as a summary for that endpoint.

On my request model, each property has a  describing the property. This all works fine except for when I try to add a summary to an Enum.

For example, I have the following property in my class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Domain Model Class
/// </summary>
public DomainModelClass? AssetDomainModelClass { get; set; }
```

And `DomainModelClass` is an Enum

When I go to the swagger page, there is no description on `AssetDomainModelClass`

[image]

Additionally I looked at the json that is created, and it does not contain a description for the Enum field

[image]

But the summary works for all non Enum properties, such as the AssetId one right above my example. How can I get a summary to attach to Enum values?

I am using `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore (6.0.7)`

Answer (score 3):

I hope you found this when you needed it, but for people like me:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.UseInlineDefinitionsForEnums();
}
```

Comment: tried everything and this is the only one that worked.